# C#: How to add a full ContextMenu to MenuItem as a submenu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

Using .NET and Windows Forms:

What is the sortest way to add a full `ContextMenu` to a `MenuItem`?

I mean:

```
private void AddSubMenu(MenuItem item, ContextMenu menu)
{
   // I want to add the full menu to the menu item as a submenu

   // I could iterate the items of the menu and add them to the item
   // but I guess that there is a smarter way to do this
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, that's really simple:

```
private void AddSubMenu(MenuItem item, ContextMenu contextMenu)
{
    item.MergeMenu(contextMenu);
}
```

and obviously, all the event handlers subscribed before the merge will still work and will be triggered by both menus.

Comment: i think that will append the context menu  to the Menu instead of adding it as a submenu.

Comment: No, it adds all the `ContextMenu` items under the `MenuItem`. I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Well i didn't found any much smarter way then iterating strategy. However you can leave that to [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.menuitemcollection.addrange.aspx) function. So your code becomes.

```
private void AddSubMenu(MenuItem item, ContextMenu menu)
{
    item.MenuItems.AddRange(menu.MenuItems);
}
```

MenuItems return a MenuItemCollection and Addrange Takes such Collection so both satisfied and we are save from doing the Iteration stuff.

Comment: This does not compile. I'm using .NET 1.4 yes, I live in the paleolithic ;-). It seems that cannot convert a ManuItemCollection to an array: `(1497): Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Menu.MenuItemCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[]'`